# Indian light music: Can a light music/film song exceed 7 notes?

Tags: theory, piano, keyboard, indian-classical

I've been practicing to play song 'Har Ghadi Badal Rahi He'

from the movie 'Kal Ho Na Ho', I extracted notes/swaras of that music by hearing.

I got these notes/swaras combinations:
C D E F G A A# B

8 notes / swaras in total, which is contrary to what I learnt; a song/music cannot exceed 7 notes.

*Side note: I searched over Internet for notations as well, many websites had wrote 8 notes.*

How is that possible [8 notes]?
Genuinely looking for answers.

Thank you.

Comment: Who told you "a song/music cannot exceed 7 notes."? That's not correct at all.

Comment: This song has a chord progression.  Already it's not likely to follow raags strictly just based on that alone; raags are really scales that you sing over a fixed drone

Answer (score 5):

In Indian classical music, every Raag's Aroh and Avroh (ascending and Descending) **must not contain less than five or more than 7 notes**. This rule defines the Jati of a Raag.
There are three main Jaties (Categories) of Indian Raags:

1. Heptatonic or Sampooran or all seven notes
2. Hexatonic or Chhadav or 6 notes
3. Pentatonic or Audav or 5 notes

However songs do not have to strictly follow the grammar of Raags. Also most raag based songs do not comply with every aspects of the raag.

Reference: http://www.ragopedia.com/raga/jati.html

Comment: It is only a good rule of thumb that a ragam must have between five and seven notes in its *arohanam* and *avarohanam*, but that is not strictly necessary. There are many legitimate ragams that employ more or less notes.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible for a song/music to exceed 7 notes/*swaras*. Because in total there are 12 notes/*swaras* in music (viz. *Sa, Komal Re, Re, Komal Ga, Ga, Ma, Tivra/Kori Ma, Pa, Komal Dha, Dha, Komal Ni and Ni*). *Yaman Kalyan* is a good example of such a *Raga*, where more than 7, i.e. 8 notes/*swaras* (viz. *Sa, Re, Ga, Ma, Komal Ma, Pa, Dha, Ni*) are used, and *Bhairavi* is a *Raga* where all the 12 notes/*swaras* are used.

But what you have learnt, that `a song/music cannot exceed 7 notes is also not wrong`. Because according to some, as the *komal Re, Komal Ga, Komal Dha, Komal Ni* and *tivra/kori Ma* are derived from their own respective *Shuddha swaras*/notes so, they are not individual notes/swaras but are a part of their own respective *Suddha swaras*/notes and they don't count them.

The conclusion is that both the theories are correct. What you have learnt is even correct and what others might have learnt is also correct.

Answer (score 3):

Okay so according to the notes you said, basically there are two 7ths in the scale right? A and A#? One is the minor seventh and the other is the major seventh respectively. This corresponds to having two "Ni's" in the swaras. So this is a fun aspect of some ragas where on ascension, they would use different notes like in this one.. On the ascent it's the major seventh (Pure Ni) and on the descent they would use the minor seventh (Komal Ni). This is the Raga Khamaj.. Even the song 'Mitwa' is in Raga Khamaj. You can notice it in the chorus when he sings "Mi-thu-wa" it is (P-N-S) (5th, maj7th, octave) and the next line it is "Ka-he-dhad" it is (P-n-n..) (5th, min7th, min7th)..
Hope this makes sense. 
Basically, this song uses both the A and A# like in Raga Khamaj for flavour and variety and it's completely possible. Major seventh is used on the ascent and on the descent minor seventh is used.

Answer (score 2):

Ragas can have any number of notes from 5 to 12. A rule of thumb for ragas is that the **ascending & descending scales (*aroh* and *avaroh*) separately have 5-7 notes each. But the ascending and descending scales need not be symmetrical. So, when both ascending & descending scales are taken into account, many ragas end up having more than 7 notes.**

When a raga is asymmetrical, it usually happens that the higher pitched variant of a note is used in ascending phrases, and the lower pitched variant of that same note is used in descending phrases.

So, take Raag Khamaj for instance: (S G m P D N S' / S' n D P m G R S), which uses both variants of ni (7), giving it a total of 8 notes. Or Raag Kedar (S m G P, M P D N S' / S' D n D P, M P D P m R S), which uses both variants of ma (4) as well as ni (7), giving it a total of 9 notes.

So, there are ragas that use only 5 notes, all the way to ragas that use all 12 notes. And these are serious ragas I'm talking about.

When it comes to semiclassical or light classical music, the artist can add notes to an existing raga in their own way, so even ragas that traditionally have 7 or fewer notes can be performed with more notes in these settings.

The song you refer to is not really based on classical music. It would fall into the genre of popular/film music. And yes, it can have any number of notes.

P.S.: As Digital Eagle says, in Indian music there are only 7 *swaras.* But five of these have two variants each, making a total of 12 standard pitches in an octave. When we write this in English, we say there are 12 notes in an octave. But in Indian context, it might be less confusing to say there are 7 notes and 12 standard pitches in an octave.

Answer (score 0):

Many types of keys and modes, particularly in the Western musical tradition, are *defined* as 7 notes.  There are still many other keys with more or less notes.

Additionally, much — if not most — music in those 7-note keys uses all 7 of those notes plus accidentals (i.e., sharped/flattened versions of those notes).  This is common and violates no hard rules, and very few made-up ones.

Keys are only a guideline or basis, and should be completely ignored (if the composer wishes) in favor of what sounds good or accomplishes the composer's intent.

Answer (score 0):

I am not expert in Indian classical music, but I understand there are rules for constructing a Raag.   But is your film song classical Indian music?  It sounds to me like contemporary international pop, with infulences from Indian classical.  So it can do whatever it likes!